# Rails debug assets:precompile: how to identify offending file(s)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, debugging, encoding, rake, asset-pipeline

I'm a bit desperate; been trying to debug this problem for days. ANYONE have any idea how to troubleshoot? Perhaps identify the file(s) that are creating the encoding problem?

FWIW: This works in dev environment: `RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile --trace`

But this fails on 'production' server...no idea how to begin troubleshooting:

```
$ RAILS_ENV=production RAILS_GROUPS=assets bundle exec rake assets:precompile --trace
** Invoke assets:precompile (first_time)
** Invoke assets:environment (first_time)
** Execute assets:environment
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
** Execute assets:precompile
I, [2013-09-26T10:54:13.904512 #8431]  INFO -- : Writing /rails/myapp/releases/20130926175008/public/assets/sort_asc-9348a2efdfbcfa28135e10d4f7b42d0d.png
I, [2013-09-26T10:54:13.945109 #8431]  INFO -- : Writing /rails/myapp/releases/20130926175008/public/assets/sort_asc_disabled-30ae6b96c67982047ca4cfa0b8ce81b2.png
I, [2013-09-26T10:54:14.007435 #8431]  INFO -- : Writing /rails/myapp/releases/20130926175008/public/assets/sort_both-8018c940cc83bb4cf2bf0e68e41fdcc0.png
I, [2013-09-26T10:54:14.011733 #8431]  INFO -- : Writing /rails/myapp/releases/20130926175008/public/assets/sort_desc-05521e27371d9dd4e6febce9314bc7ed.png
I, [2013-09-26T10:54:14.017370 #8431]  INFO -- : Writing /rails/myapp/releases/20130926175008/public/assets/sort_desc_disabled-a3215e17d6bf077db02468b895fee228.png
rake aborted!
Caught Encoding::CompatibilityError at '["ok","!function(e,t': incompatible encoding regexp match (ASCII-8BIT regexp with UTF-8 string)
  (in /rails/myapp/releases/20130926175008/app/assets/javascripts/application.js)
/rails/myapp/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/json-1.8.0/lib/json/pure/parser.rb:242:in `rescue in parse_string'
/rails/myapp/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/json-1.8.0/lib/json/pure/parser.rb:213:in `parse_string'
/rails/myapp/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/json-1.8.0/lib/json/pure/parser.rb:257:in `parse_value'
/rails/myapp/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/json-1.8.0/lib/json/pure/parser.rb:121:in `parse'
/rails/myapp/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/json-1.8.0/lib/json/common.rb:155:in `parse'
/rails/myapp/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/json-1.8.0/lib/json/common.rb:334:in `load'
/rails/myapp/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/execjs-2.0.1/lib/execjs/external_runtime.rb:62:in `extract_result'
/rails/myapp/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/execjs-2.0.1/lib/execjs/external_runtime.rb:28:in `block in exec'
/rails/myapp/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/execjs-2.0.1/lib/execjs/external_runtime.rb:41:in `compile_to_tempfile'
/rails/myapp/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/execjs-2.0.1/lib/execjs/external_runtime.rb:27:in `exec'
/rails/myapp/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/uglifier-2.2.1/lib/uglifier.rb:176:in `really_compile'
/rails/myapp/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/uglifier-2.2.1/lib/uglifier.rb:100:in `compile'
/rails/myapp/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.10.0/lib/sprockets/uglifier_compressor.rb:25:in `evaluate'
/rails/myapp/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/tilt-1.4.1/lib/tilt/template.rb:103:in `render'
/rails/myapp/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.10.0/lib/sprockets/context.rb:197:in `block in evaluate'
/rails/myapp/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.10.0/lib/sprockets/context.rb:194:in `each'
/rails/myapp/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.10.0/lib/sprockets/context.rb:194:in `evaluate'
/rails/myapp/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.10.0/lib/sprockets/bundled_asset.rb:25:in `initialize'
/rails/myapp/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.10.0/lib/sprockets/base.rb:377:in `new'
/rails/myapp/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.10.0/lib/sprockets/base.rb:377:in `build_asset'
/rails/myapp/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.10.0/lib/sprockets/index.rb:94:in `block in build_asset'
/rails/myapp/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.10.0/lib/sprockets/caching.rb:58:in `cache_asset'
/rails/myapp/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.10.0/lib/sprockets/index.rb:93:in `build_asset'
/rails/myapp/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.10.0/lib/sprockets/base.rb:287:in `find_asset'
/rails/myapp/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.10.0/lib/sprockets/index.rb:61:in `find_asset'
/rails/myapp/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.10.0/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:211:in `block in find_asset'
/rails/myapp/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.10.0/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:257:in `benchmark'
/rails/myapp/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.10.0/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:210:in `find_asset'
/rails/myapp/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.10.0/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:119:in `block in compile'
/rails/myapp/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.10.0/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:118:in `each'
/rails/myapp/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.10.0/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:118:in `compile'
/rails/myapp/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-rails-2.0.0/lib/sprockets/rails/task.rb:60:in `block (3 levels) in define'
/rails/myapp/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.10.0/lib/rake/sprocketstask.rb:146:in `with_logger'
/rails/myapp/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-rails-2.0.0/lib/sprockets/rails/task.rb:59:in `block (2 levels) in define'
/rails/myapp/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:236:in `call'
/rails/myapp/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:236:in `block in execute'
/rails/myapp/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:231:in `each'
/rails/myapp/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:231:in `execute'
/rails/myapp/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:175:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/rails/myapp/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:168:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/rails/myapp/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:161:in `invoke'
/rails/myapp/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:149:in `invoke_task'
/rails/myapp/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/rails/myapp/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `each'
/rails/myapp/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `block in top_level'
/rails/myapp/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:115:in `run_with_threads'
/rails/myapp/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:100:in `top_level'
/rails/myapp/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:78:in `block in run'
/rails/myapp/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:165:in `standard_exception_handling'
/rails/myapp/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:75:in `run'
/rails/myapp/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.0/bin/rake:33:in `<top (required)>'
/rails/myapp/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/bin/rake:23:in `load'
/rails/myapp/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/bin/rake:23:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => assets:precompile
```

Gemfile (as requested):

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby '2.0.0'

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.0.0'
gem 'pg'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'

gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 1.2'

group :doc do
  # bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
  gem 'sdoc', require: false
end

group :development, :test do
  gem 'rspec-rails'
  gem 'factory_girl_rails'
  gem 'guard-rspec'
  # gem 'debugger'
end

group :development do
  gem 'annotate'
  gem 'spork-rails', github: 'sporkrb/spork-rails'
  gem 'guard-spork'
  gem 'awesome_print'
  gem 'better_errors'
  gem 'binding_of_caller'
  gem 'pry-rails' #substitute pry for irb
end

group :test do
  gem 'selenium-webdriver'
  gem 'capybara'
  gem 'faker'
  gem 'database_cleaner'
  gem 'poltergeist'
  gem 'launchy'
end

gem 'rvm-capistrano' #, group: :development
gem 'haml-rails'
# gem 'zurb-foundation'
# gem 'foundicons-rails'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', :git => 'git://github.com/thomas-mcdonald/bootstrap-sass.git' #, :branch => '3'
gem 'kaminari'
gem 'ancestry'
gem 'twitter-typeahead-rails'
# gem 'bootstrap-typeahead-rails' #TODO
gem 'hogan_assets'
gem 'awesome_print'
gem 'multi_json', '1.7.8' # error in cap deploy with version 1.7.9
# gem 'json' # not necessary before multi_json deploy failure

gem 'textacular'
gem 'jquery-datatables-rails', github: 'rweng/jquery-datatables-rails'
```

Comment: try searching your assets directory for `["ok","!function(e,t`

Comment: @luri G. I've tried searching *my* assets for that javascript with `grep -r '!function(e' .` but it turns up nothing. However, I'm using *mostly* coffeescript so the syntax is a bit different. perhaps this comes after coffee is pre-compiled?!?

Comment: I suggest you to remove files (directives) from your `application.js` manifest to identify the file that is causing the problem. You can run `rake assets:precompile` in development.

Comment: Ya, problem is it `rake assets:precompile` works in development (see second paragraph in OP).

Comment: @meltemi I've added `config.assets.js_compressor` setting from prod to dev config, and that helped in replicating the production issue.

Answer (score 2):

I would just start a cycle of removing a file from your manifest, and then trying to deploy.  If that didn't work, I'd remove the next file from the manifest, and so on until I found the one that was causing the issue.

Comment: Oh, please. One at a time? Do a binary search, like a real programmer. Take away half of all the files in the list. If it fails, take away half of what's left, else restore half of what you took away. Repeat until you find the offending file.

Answer (score 1):

Just faced with similar issue - got InvalidByteSequenceError during assets:precompile. What I did was - I edited the sprockets gem code a bit to "puts" some debug info, current file name being processed in particular. Then I ran precompile again, found the file based on the debug output, and fixed it. Then of course I reverted gem changes. You can use the same approach since you have the backtrace. Moreover, you could even debug the asstes:precompile task (either by inline debugger or through your favourite IDE. Hope this helps!

Comment: Please post your diff or at least a filename!  You almost just made my day.

Comment: I'm glad I've made your day, @djvs. I have no diff because it was a minute deal. I just posted my experience resolving this issue in less than a minute. Yeah it may sound ugly but it saved me a lot of time, for a project with hundreds of complex assets

Comment: @neolancer I literally ended up replacing Sprockets with Webpack after encountering this (in the end, Sprockets + babel or similar was just failing for god knows what reason - had it up to here with Sprockets after so many years)